# How to accept values within a certain range 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how to i set a range between certain number when entering numbers in?

Thanks

I tried using a `do`  loop but it just kept looping even when i entered numbers within the range

```
 public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int row, col, i, j;
            int a[][]=new int[10][10];

            do{
            Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the order of a square matrix :");
            row=sc.nextInt();
            col=sc.nextInt();
            /* checking order of matrix and then if true then enter the values
             * into the matrix a[][]
            */

            if(row == col)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter elements in the matrix:"+row*col);

                for(i=0; i<row; i++)
                {

                    for(j=0; j<col; j++) 
                    a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                }

            }
            } while(row != col);
           // Display the entered value
            System.out.println ("You have entered the following matrix");

            for (i=0; i<row; i++)
           {
               for (j=0; j<col; j++)
               System.out.print (a[i][j] + " ");
               System.out.println ();
            }
```

Comment: There are two places where numbers are entered, which one are you referring to? And if `row` has to be equal to `col`, why can't the user just enter one value instead for both `row` and `col`?

Comment: referring to the second one. Where i have to enter the number values for the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should learn to extract tasks in methods and add Javadoc to make your code easier to read.

Hope this helps you:

```
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dimension;
    System.out.println("Enter the dimension of a squared matrix :");
    dimension = sc.nextInt();
    final int col = dimension;
    final int row = dimension;
    int[][] matrix = fillMatrix(row, col);
    displayMatrix(matrix);
}

/**
 * Prints the given matrix to console
 *
 * @param matrix to be printed
 */
private static void displayMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println("You have entered the following matrix");
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

/**
 * Uses users input to fill create a matrix with the given dimensions
 *
 * @param row matrix row dimension
 * @param col matrix column dimension
 *
 * @return a filled matrix
 */
private static int[][] fillMatrix(final int row, final int col) {
    System.out.println("Enter elements in the matrix:" + row * col);
    int[][] matrix = new int[col][row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            int tmpNumber = 0;
            while(tmpNumber<15 || tmpNumber >60){
                System.out.println(String.format("Enter value for row %s, column %s between 15 and 60", i, j));
                tmpNumber = sc.nextInt();
            }
            matrix[i][j] = tmpNumber;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the dimension of a squared matrix :
2
Enter elements in the matrix:4
Enter value for row 0, column 0 between 15 and 60
2
Enter value for row 0, column 0 between 15 and 60
17
Enter value for row 0, column 1 between 15 and 60
18
Enter value for row 1, column 0 between 15 and 60
19
Enter value for row 1, column 1 between 15 and 60
20
You have entered the following matrix
17 18 
19 20
```

Comment: sorry but my aim is to be able to set aa max and min value on the numbers being entered into the array. For example only allow numbers within the range to 15 and 60

Comment: Updated. Like this?

Comment: yes thankyou very much but i was wondering if u can keep it in one public class like the way i did it

Answer (score 0):

First add the bounds as constant

```
final int LOWER_BOUND = 0;
final int UPPER_BOUND = 100;
```

Then check in the loop each entered value against the bounds before adding the value to the array

```
int temp = sc.nextInt();
if (temp >= LOWER_BOUND && temp <= UPPER_BOUND) {
    a[i][j] = temp;
} else {
    System.out.println("Values has to be between " + LOWER_BOUND + " and " + UPPER_BOUND);
}
```

The problem remaining is that you can't use you `for` loops as they are now since the user might need several iterations to enter the right value. One simple solution is to surround the above code in a infinite `while` loop that is not exited until a correct value is given.

```
while (true) {
    int temp = sc.nextInt();
    if (temp >= LOWER_BOUND && temp <= UPPER_BOUND) {
        a[i][j] = temp;
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Values has to be between " + LOWER_BOUND + " and " + UPPER_BOUND);
    }
}
```

A better solution might be to replace the innermost`for` loop with a `while` loop where you increase `j` manually when a correct value has been entered

Comment: my aim is to be able to set aa max and min value on the numbers being entered into the array. For example only allow numbers within the range to 15 and 60

Comment: @Jack Surely you can edit in my code in your  code yourself and change the constants to the values you want? Come back if you ran into some issue or have further questions about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example for your cause.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        String getInputLine;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[][] = new int[10][10];
        // for number of rows in your array
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            // for number of columns in your array
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {

                // print this message on screen
                System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
                // get input from next line
                getInputLine = sc.nextLine();
                //if you haven't match one or more integers
                while (!getInputLine.matches("\\d{1,}")) {
                    System.out.print("Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: ");
                    getInputLine = sc.nextLine(); // Prints error, gets user to input again
                }
                number = Integer.parseInt(getInputLine); // parse input into an integer
                a[i][j] = number; // store it to array at position i j
                System.out.println("You've set number " + number + " for array[" + i + " " + j + "]"); // Prints the passcode


            }
        }
        //print your array
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }
}
```